# Check variables and add them to comma separated list

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, csv

I have 4 javascript variables:

```
a = 'first';
b = 'second';
c = 'third';
d = 'fourth';
```

What i want to achieve is to get them separated by comma, BUT. Sometimes where could be situations that some variables could be empty. Here is some of examples:

EXAMPLE1:

```
a = 'first';
b = '';
c = 'third';
d = '';
```

OUTPUT should be: first, third

EXAMPLE2:

```
a = '';
b = 'second';
c = '';
d = 'fourth';
```

OUTPUT should be: second, fourth

Maybe someone could help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simpler solution (but not necessarily the more efficient) is :

```
var arr = [];
if (a) 
  arr.push(a);

if (b) 
  arr.push(b);

if (c) 
  arr.push(c);

if (d) 
  arr.push(d);

var commaSeparated = arr.join(',');
```

I like using an array for this kind of problem because you don't have to worry about append or not the commas to your result string.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()` as shown :-

```
a = '';
b = 'second';
c = '';
d = 'fourth';

var arr=[];
arr.push(a)
arr.push(b)
arr.push(c)
arr.push(d)
var newarr = arr.filter(function(value){
  return $.trim(value) != '' && value != null;
});
newarr = newarr.join(',');
alert(newarr);
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/03r4nq5h/1/)

Comment: Thanks for solution. However i'm getting something like ,second,,fourth. Strange. However the next comment solves this. Thanks again.

Comment: @MIC..this is not possible you can check fiddle also..it will work like a charm..there must be problem somewhere else ... maybe whitespace...i have updated the answer using `$.trim()` you can try it.

Comment: Yeah i saw that fiddle works fine. Sorry, i think i forgot to mention that it's probably the problem on my side as it is so for sure.